# On Maps, Directions, how do I get a route's baseline duration

Tags: google-maps-navigation

How do I get Maps, Directions, to give me a route's baseline duration (as given by maps.google.com) as opposed to just the "In current traffic" duration?

maps.google.com gives me a duration (what I am calling baseline) plus "In current traffic" duration. Maps however gives me just one duration equal to the maps.google.com "In current traffic" duration. I want Maps to give me the baseline duration.